# Factorization for frozen state methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control, linearization

Considering the inverted pendulum equation as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= \sin(x_1) - 0.5x_2
\end{split}
$$

Now if I want to apply frozen state methods, I can use factorization to get a pseudo linear system

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{x}
$$

for example by factorizing out $x_1$ like

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= \sin(x_1)\frac{1}{x_1}x_1 - 0.5x_2
\end{split}
$$

which gives the state dependent $\mathbf{A}$-matrix as

$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
\frac{\sin(x_1)}{x_1} & -0.5
\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$

Remark: The singularity can be removed here using L'Hopitals rule.

**However**: To me it is not clear how to choose such a factorization. In especially I could also have chosen $x_2$ instead of $x_1$ for the factorization - which one should be prefered then? In this special case it seems to be $x_1$ because the term $\sin(x_1)$ depends only on $x_1$ and it allows nicely to remove the singularity.

**But**: How to do this in general? Assuming a system like

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= f(x_1, x_2) - 0.5x_2
\end{split}
$$

with $f$ nonlinear. Should I go for $f(x_1, x_2)\frac{1}{x_1}x_1$, for  $f(x_1, x_2)\frac{1}{x_2}x_2$ or maybe even a linear combination of these?

Is there any theory/best practise available how to do this?

Comment: Never heard of this method, but according to [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) if your function $f(x_1, x_2)$ is zero at the origin and smooth enough, it has unique representation as $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 \cdot g_1 (x_1, x_2) + x_2 \cdot g_2(x_1, x_2)$, where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are one-degree-less-smooth-than-$f$.

Comment: Unfortunatly this is only the case for $n = 1$ (with $n$ being the number of states). For $n > 1$ the factorization is not unique anymore.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, the uniqueness part was the only one about which I had doubts. Can you show a counterexample?

Comment: Consider for example $x_1^2x_2^2$ which can be written as $f_1(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1^2x_2)x_2$ or as $f_2(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1x_2^2)x_1$ so there exist at least two different factorizations such that $f_1(\mathbf{x}) = f_2(\mathbf{x}) \, \forall \mathbf{x}$. Therefore $f_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x}) = \alpha f_1(\mathbf{x}) + (1 - \alpha)f_2(\mathbf{x})$ is parameterizing with $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ a family of factorizations. Hence there are infinitly many factorizations.